# Getting the value of a prepopulated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-forms

How do I get the value of the field #id_start_date if the date is populated already?

I tried this:

```
var sd = $("#id_start_date").val();
$("span.start_date").text(sd);
```

and also tried putting it inside a .change() or .click() but it didn't work due to it being changed by the program and not manually.

**edit**

Here is the form section of my html.

```
....
<tr>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <td><input id="id_start_date" type="text" class="datepicker date_field" name="start_date" size="14" /></td>
</tr>
....
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Steve

Comment: can you show the html section as well?

Comment: Not the template code -- the actual HTML received by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my issue was and I figured I would post it here in case any others come across a similar issue.

There was an AJAX call being made that had the start_date in it, so I placed the code inside the AJAX call and it worked.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url whatever %}",
        dataType: "json",
        data: q,
        success: function(json) {
            $("#id_maturity_date").val(json.maturity_date);
            var mat = $("#id_maturity_date").val();
            $("span.mat_date").text(mat);

            $("#id_start_date").val(json.start_date);
            var sd = $("#id_start_date").val();
            $("span.start_date").text(sd);

            $("#id_term_years").val(json.term_years);
            $("#id_term_months").val(json.term_months);
            ...
        }
    });
```

For some reason, the .change() doesn't fire when its being populated this way so I was never able to get the value unless I went inside the AJAX call.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If that date is in the `span`, then you should be able to do this</strike>

`$("#id_start_date span.start_date").text();`

Looking at the html you just posted, you could do this

`$('#id_start_date').val();`

Comment: the date isn't in the span.  I'm assigning the value to that span

Comment: right.   My real problem is getting .change() to trigger.  When it gets populated automatically, it doesn't trigger the change.  Only if I was to manually change it afterwards

Comment: Its being populated by my rate sheet where they click on a rate and it inputs all the data into the form.  Then it takes the current date and places it in the datefield.

Answer (score 0):

if is a `input text` your code will work:

```
var sd = $("#id_start_date").val();
```

but if is a text ( string field )

you must use:

```
var sd = $("#id_start_date").text();
```

Comment: I'm not getting a value for start_date though

Comment: well, if u put something inside the `input` your code will work, but if is a db result or anything else, u neet to set the code in your call back, when the input will be with some value. all this depends when u fire this event.